# Can you create an Index template using Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to attach an Index Lifecycle Policy I have defined in Kibana to my indexes, but it says to attach to an Index Template. I don't see anywhere to define an Index Template in Kibana. Is the only method to do so through the elasticsearch API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index template can be created in Kibana.
The path is http://host.of.kibana/app/kibana#/management/elasticsearch/index_management
[image]

Comment: In which version?

Answer (score 0):

There is PUT template API avaliable through curl or Kibana, just set index patterns for indices you want.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html